# Requesting for POST method but only GET is working

Tags: python, django, post, get, request

The Form in register.html request for POST method but GET method is working. Submit is calling register method in views.py using GET method, but this shouldn't be happening.

Error :

Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/Profile/register/register/

views.py

```html
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import messages

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        return render(request, 'register.html')
```

register.html

```html
<form action="register" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="Submit">
</form>
```

urls.py of Project

```html
from re import template
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    path('Profile/', include('Profile.urls')),

    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),

    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="login.html"),
    name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(),
    name='logout'),
    path('reset_password/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), 
    name = 'reset_password'),
    path('reset_password_sent/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(),
    name='password_reset_done'),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),
    name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset_password_complete/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(),
    name='password_reset_complete')
]
```

urls.py of Profile app

```html
from django.urls import path
from Profile import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('profile/', views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The URL is `register/`. Because you do not use a trailing slash, Django will make a redirect with a slash, but that will thus result in a GET request, not a POST request.

You thus should work with:

```
<form action="/profile/register/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="Submit">
</form>
```

or better is to work with the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url):

```
<form action="{% url 'register' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying same using {% url 'register' %} but it didn't work. Now I made changes as you stated after running the server again. It worked. Thanks